# Paperclip :path arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Whilst developing locally, I don't want any images I upload to my s3 bucket to overwrite, or affect in any way those already uploaded through the production app.

My :path argument looks like this

```
:path => "profile_photo/:id/photo_:style.:extension"
```

Which means that an uploaded file will be at `profile_photo/1/photo_normal.png`

Fine, but if I upload an image for my resource with :id 1, it will overwrite the photo that may have been uploaded by an RL user.

The problem could be solved if there was a way to get the current environment, something like this, maybe?

```
:path => "profile_photo/:environment/:id/photo_:style.:extension"
```

to output a file path

```
profile_photo/production/1/photo_normal.png
```

or
    profile_photo/development/1/photo_normal.png

This would be ideal, and I don't really want to create a separate bucket for development, I'm just a little strange like that.

I've looked for a place to find which symbols are available to pass as arguments, no success.

How have others solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb#L33) and [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb#L74), I'm pretty sure you can do:

```
:path => "profile_photo/:rails_env/:id/photo_:style.:extension"
```

Comment: rails_env is part of interpolation already, so this suggestion must work.